# node-sass-middleware not compiling

Tags: node.js, express, sass

Im trying to get the node-sass-middleware working with with express. The app runs with no errors

```
...(modules)
var sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
//---- LOAD SASS -----//
// adding the sass middleware
var srcPath = __dirname + '/scss';
var destPath = __dirname + '/public/stylesheets';
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: srcPath,
  dest: destPath,
  debug: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with the way I'm attempting to compile the sass?

file structure :

```
app
controllers
routes
public
-stylesheets
scss
...
```

Comment: What version of Express are you using?  In example the package.json they are using connect 2.7.9.  The convention has changed a lot so you may have to do something like app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: srcPath,
  dest: destPath,
  debug: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
})());

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how app.js should be:

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: srcPath,
  dest: destPath,
  debug: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
}),
express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Also your  main scss file should be named style.scss and be inside scss/stylesheets/ directory.

You should see a log like this, if you have correctly loaded the module:

```
  source : /Users/abc/Desktop/SO/SO_node/scss/stylesheets/style.scss
  dest : /Users/abc/Desktop/SO/SO_node/public/stylesheets/stylesheets/style.css
  read : /Users/abc/Desktop/SO/SO_node/public/stylesheets/stylesheets/style.css
  render : /Users/abc/Desktop/SO/SO_node/scss/stylesheets/style.scss
```

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. It's ironic how no example of correct structure of `node-sass-middleware` usage is present in almost nowhere! This was the only example I found!

Comment: The main problem is the path to *.scss file. The duplicate names "scss/stylesheets/"

Comment: Moving the express.static call below the sass-middleware call worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A problem could also be that you want to compile `scss`

instead of `sass`. Therefore set `indentedSyntax` to `false`.

```
app.use(require('node-sass-middleware')({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'scss'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  indentedSyntax : false,
  sourceMap: true
}));
```

Or remove it completly. Express-generator adds this value on default.

Answer (score 0):

Better go for **[grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass)**. Simple configuration, automated task (thanks to grunt) and also faster compiling time because of **libsass**, which is the C version of the original Ruby compiler for SASS. Compile sass/scss files in 0.3 seconds instead of 3.