# node-sass-middleware not compiling sass files

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I'm really struggling to make sense of the node-sass-middleware. I've required and called it as per the [doc](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware). However, the sass file is not compiled, nor is anything logged to my console.

```
const sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(
  bodyParser.json(),
  bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}),

  sassMiddleware({
    src: __dirname + '/style/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/style',
    debug: true,
    indentedSyntax: true,
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
  }),

  express.static(__dirname + '/public')
);
```

I've looked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554606/node-sass-middleware-not-compiling) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711155/node-sass-middleware-not-rendering-using-express) for solutions, as well as the above mentioned docs, but nothing I've tried have given me the wanted result, including changing the sass file to scss.

Dependencies as shown:

```
  "dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
  "express": "^4.16.2",
  "firebase-admin": "^5.8.2",
  "morgan": "^1.9.0",
  "node-sass-middleware": "^0.11.0",
  "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4"
},
```

Additionally, linking to a stylesheet that obviously doesn't exist does not return a 404. Which is weird?

Comment: Same thing for me, I have no debug console output ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to check how you are linking the stylesheet in the "/public/your.html", make sure you are referencing the stylesheet like:  without any prefix then reload your broswer and check again.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer my code**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const port = process.env.PORT || "3000";
var sassMiddleware = require("node-sass-middleware");

// Setup SASS directories
var path = require("path");
var srcPath = __dirname + "/sass";
var destPath = __dirname + "/public/stylesheets";
app.use(
  sassMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, "sass"),
    dest: path.join(__dirname, "public/css"),
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: "compressed",
    prefix: "/css",
  }),
  // set default folder for importing css,jsand images
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))
);

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//routes
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home", { title: "Home" });
});
app.get("/contact", function (req, res) {
  res.render("contact", { title: "Contact" });
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("server is listening at port", port);
});
```

**Refer my git repository**
https://github.com/rockytechtips/node-ejs-boilerplate